Why is ProblemDetails not being returned in the HTTP response from my 'IExceptionHandler' implementation`?
I'm trying to implement global exception handling in my ASP.NET Core application. My goal is to catch all unhandled exceptions and return a standardized error response using the ProblemDetails object.
public class GlobalExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger = Log.ForContext(typeof(GlobalExceptionHandler));

    public async ValueTask<bool> TryHandleAsync(
        HttpContext httpContext,
        Exception exception,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.Error(exception, "Global Exception Handler");

        var problemDetails = new ProblemDetails
        {
            Status = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
            Title = "An exception occurred",
            Detail = exception.Message
        };

        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = problemDetails.Status.Value;
        httpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/problem+json";

        await httpContext.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(problemDetails, cancellationToken);

        return true;
    }
}

Problem: The HTTP status code is correctly set to 500, but the ProblemDetails object is not being returned in the response body. Instead, the response body is empty, and the client doesn't receive the expected JSON error details.
Why is the ProblemDetails object not being returned in the response body and how can I ensure that the ProblemDetails object is properly serialized and returned?
Thanks in advance!

Thank you everyone for your answers, they helped me eliminate the possible causes and arrive at a solution. The issue was due to a memory stream being closed before the exception handler could write to it. I had to replace the using MemoryStream blocks to work without the using, and it works fine now. Thanks again!
Previous code:
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    f.CopyTo(ms);
    r = ms.ToArray();
}

Changed to:
var ms = new MemoryStream();
try
{
    f.CopyTo(ms);
    r = ms.ToArray();
}
finally
{
    ms.Dispose();
}


I create a new project of my ASP.NET Core App (Model-View-Controller)  use .net 8.0,then copy your  GlobalExceptionHandler  class, then config it in the program.cs,It works well.
Program.cs:
using WebApplication1;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using WebApplication1.Data;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddExceptionHandler<GlobalExceptionHandler>();
builder.Services.AddProblemDetails();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

 app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();


app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();

HomeController.cs:
public ViewResult Index() => throw new Exception("Index error");

the result is:

My Visual Studio version  is 17.10.5 and .net version is .NET 8.0. You can check your .net and Visual Studio version and the order of registering in Program.cs.



Make sure that on startup you register all needed services and setup middleware:
// adding needed services
builder.Services.AddExceptionHandler<GlobalExceptionHandler>();
builder.Services.AddProblemDetails();

// ...

// Register middleware
app.UseExceptionHandler();

After adding those, your example worked like charm :)

Yes I have these configured correctly. but for some reason it's not working. Is it possible for the AddProblemDetails() method to be somehow unregistered due to other additions to the builder services?

Maybe you apply those conditionally? Could you share the code where you register everything?

Okay so I have figured out that the WriteAsJsonAsync method isn't writing anything to the response. It does get executed, but even if I write a plain string instead of the problemDetails variable, nothing is shown in the response tab of the network call.

Hm where did you called UseExceptionHandler? Because order of registering things in pipeline matters a lot :)

app.UseExceptionHandler();```

The other things are registered later e.g. swagger, httpsredirection, routing, middleware and mapcontrollers.

just a few opinions;
Can you try omitting content-type. Just set status code and pass problemdetails object to WriteAsJsonAsync? You can also test serializing object yourself and pass it with "await context.Response.WriteAsync(serialized json);"
Btw, what is your asp.net core version? IExceptionHandler supposed to work since 8.0
Are you sure content type is correct? "application/problem+json"? Default one should be application/json. The problem might be related to content type and or formatting. You can take a look at the related  MS guide.
You sure there is no another middleware after this which might be changing the response?
If possible, I would debug at breakpoint.

On further exception, I have figured that the code break at the WriteAsJsonAsync method with a 'Cannot access a closed stream' exception.

Can you track stacks to see where the error coming from? You may pinpoint what stream and where its coming from

You sure there is no another middleware after this which might be changing the response? As Michal mentioned order of registrations/middlewares matter.

Are you sure content type is correct? "application/problem+json"? Default one should be application/json. The problem might be related to content type and or formatting. You can take a look at the related  [MS guide][1].
Can you test sending text with text content type? Client may not accept it, you can test it with a test client at your side if possible. You might filter out some possibilities.
Or you can just put a breakpoint at writeasync and go step by step to find root cause. I think you can filter out many  possibilities this way.

This is my stack trace:
at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.IO.MemoryStream.WriteAsync(ReadOnlyMemory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo`1.<SerializeAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo`1.<SerializeAsync>d__9.MoveNext()```

Can you try omitting content-type.  Just set status code and pass problemdetails object to WriteAsJsonAsync?
you can also test serializing object yourself and pass it with  "await context.Response.WriteAsync(serialized json);"

btw, what is your asp.net core version? IExceptionHandler works since 8.0
